# Python Plotly Express Line Graph remvoe selection box after using figure.add_selection

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, figure

So, I have this app in which i create a figure using `plotly.express.line` and then I use the `add_selection()`  function like that :
`figure.add_selection( x0=0, y0=10, x1=10, y1=0 )` which indeed adds a selection box.
But, the issue is that I want to remove this selection box by script. I tried a lot of things like
`figure.update_layout(dragmode='zoom')` but even this doesn't remove the selection box. Is there any functions like `figure.clear_selection()` or something like that ?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes use this bit of code def clear_selection(self):
    if 'selections' in self['layout']:
        self['layout']['selections'] = ()


go.Figure.clear_selection = clear_selection

Comment: That worked! I'm going to put it in an answer just so its clear for the next person looking for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together a working example of the comment by @SquidyDev on his question above.

The top portion of the code adds Squidy's custom function 'clear_selection' to the definition of a plotly go.Figure, which can then be called inside the loop to clear the previous selection.

```
import numpy as np
from plotly import graph_objects as go


def clear_selection(self):
    """
    Custom function for cleaning selections from Plotly Figure

    """
    if 'selections' in self['layout']:
        self['layout']['selections'] = ()


go.Figure.clear_selection = clear_selection

# Normal plot, adding selection and looping through for user to interact with selection
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi)
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(
    x=t,
    y=np.sin(t),
)

for ii in range(5):
    fig.clear_selection()
    fig.add_selection(
        x0=ii, y0=-0.5,
        x1=ii+1, y1=0.75
    )
    fig.show()
    breakpoint()
```